# How Would I Use One Dictionary to be a Variable for Another Dictionary's Key Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

So I'm writing a pseudo supply and demand-based Price board for my Python final and I'm having an issue with using one dictionary to influence the values of another. To start, I have a dictionary of various metals I have base costs for.

```py
metalDict = {
  'Iron Ingot': 1,
  'Copper Ingot':10,
  'Tin Ingot':30,
  'Silver Ingot':100,
  'Gold Ingot':1000,
  'Mithral Ingot':5000}
```

Then I have a secondary dictionary that will display all information according to a variety of background calculations and import the wholesale cost from `metalDict`. This is what my code currently looks like:

```py
outputDict = {
  "metals" : ['Iron Ingots', 'Copper Ingots', 'Tin Ingots', 'Silver Ingots', 'Gold Ingots', 'mithral Ingots'],
  "wholesale" : [metalDict['Iron Ingot'], metalDict['Copper Ingot'],metalDict['Tin Ingot'],metalDict['Silver Ingot'], metalDict['Gold Ingot'], metalDict['Mithral Ingot']],
  'city 1' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'city 2' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'city 3' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'city 4' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  'city 5' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
```

I want to use the `metalDict` base costs (which change based on a very basic production algorithm I wrote) to be part of an equation that updates the costs in cities 1 - 5. This may not be possible or I may need to tackle this another way (maybe creating a dictionary for each city?); I'm not sure since I'm fairly new to Python.

Also, I'm using Numpy and Pandas for outputs, so maybe they have functionality I'm not aware of yet.

What I have done is try and iterate the value changes through a `for` loop but I'm getting a key error `'city 1'` (I have cut out my demand code for the sake of forcing the change to happen regardless of my `'city 1'` needs).

```py
city1Needs = np.random.randint (2, size=100)
city1Demand = 40
if city1Demand <= 40:
  for key, value in outputDict.items():
    if key == 'city 1':
      Outputdict['city 1'] = (metalDict[key]/2) + metalDict[key]
```

What I would expect to happen is it takes each of the row indices of `'city 1'` and to the math corresponding to each of the values in `metalDict`'s rows. So my table would look something like this (I could not figure out how to expand the table in the editor so this would just be 2 of the rows and columns as opposed to the entire table):

| Wholesle Price | City one |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.5 |
| 10 | 15 |

Comment: Honestly, this seems like a problem that's just crying out for a relational database.  Have you looked at something like sqlite for this?

Comment: Why are you looping over `outputDict` if you're only updating `city 1`? And there isn't a `metalDict[key]`, because `city 1` is not a key in `metalDict`, its keys are metals, not cities.

Comment: I suspect you want to loop over the elements of the lists in `outputDict`, but it's really not clear. What do the numbers `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` represent, and why are they the same for every city? How do they relate to the calculation you want to do?

Comment: I have not like I said im fairly new to codeing and I am brand new to python. I have not learned a ton about the various packages and importables available to me in python. I'm coming from c++ and C# as the core language I have fideled with the last few years. I will take a look at sqlite thanks a ton for the suggestion!

Comment: @Barmar this is kinda why im asking the question, one of the things I ran into was it not letting me get any output with out the dictonary's being the same size (not sure why  that was) so i filled in the city's with place holders. probably not the best solution. I do want to loop over the elements of outputDict but only in cities 1-5 then use the base prices in metalDict as part of the equation to create the number in each value. i would post my whole code but im sure im doing a ton of stupid stuff in it and I really just wanted to focus on this one aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to encourage you to think about other ways to organize this data.  It's not clear what you want your final product to be, but look over what I've done here.  By keeping the list of metals and the list of cities separate, it lets me work with the data a column at a time, or a row at a time, instead of focusing on individual numbers.

```
metals = ['Iron Ingot', 'Copper Ingot', 'Tin Ingot', 'Silver Ingot', 'Gold Ingot', 'Mithral Ingot']

cities = ['city 1','city 2','city 3','city 4','city 5']

wholesale = {
  'Iron Ingot': 1,
  'Copper Ingot':10,
  'Tin Ingot':30,
  'Silver Ingot':100,
  'Gold Ingot':1000,
  'Mithral Ingot':5000}

outputDict = {}

for city in cities:
    outputDict[city] = []
    for metal in metals:
        outputDict[city].append( wholesale[metal] * 1.5 )

from pprint import pprint
pprint(outputDict)
```

Output:

```
{'city 1': [1.5, 15.0, 45.0, 150.0, 1500.0, 7500.0],
 'city 2': [1.5, 15.0, 45.0, 150.0, 1500.0, 7500.0],
 'city 3': [1.5, 15.0, 45.0, 150.0, 1500.0, 7500.0],
 'city 4': [1.5, 15.0, 45.0, 150.0, 1500.0, 7500.0],
 'city 5': [1.5, 15.0, 45.0, 150.0, 1500.0, 7500.0]}
```

Comment: Tim This is honestly what I kinda of expected (with what I know about programming) needed to happen but I figured it was worth asking just incase It was something that could happen. 

As you suggested earlier I will take a look at sqlite and start working on reorganizing my information so that I can use them on more individual levels